# Why the objects never move on the positions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I'm running the game the objects that need to move seems like shaking on place like they are trying to move but can't and also not from the start position they should be.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateEnemyTracks : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tracksPrefab;
    public GameObject curvedLinePrefab;
    public GameObject objectToMovePrefab;
    public float speed;
    public DrawRadiusAroundTurret drawRadius;
    public Transform turrent;
    [Range(1, 50)]
    public int numberOfTracks;
    [Range(1, 50)]
    public int numberOfPointsInTrack;

    private GameObject parent;
    private List<Vector3[]> tracksPointsPositions = new List<Vector3[]>();
    private GameObject[] objectsToMove;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool test = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        parent = GameObject.Find("Curved Lines");
        GenerateStartPointsOfTheTracks();
        GeneratePointsInTracks();
        //GetTracksPositions();
        objectsToMove = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Object To Move");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(test == false)
        {
            StartCoroutine(waitsome());
            
        }

        if(test == true)
        {
            if (tracksPointsPositions.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tracksPointsPositions.Count; i++)
                {
                    Move(tracksPointsPositions[i], objectsToMove);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator waitsome()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

        GetTracksPositions();
        test = true;
    }

    private void GenerateStartPointsOfTheTracks()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTracks; i++)
        {
            GameObject linePrefab = Instantiate(curvedLinePrefab);
            linePrefab.name = "Curved Line" + i.ToString();
            linePrefab.tag = "Curved Line";
            GameObject go = Instantiate(tracksPrefab, parent.transform);
            go.name = "Start Point";
            go.tag = "Start Point";

            go.transform.parent = linePrefab.transform;

            // Spawn around the absolute Unity world center (0,0,0) 
            //go.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-100f, 100f), Random.Range(-100f, 100f), Random.Range(-100f, 100f));

            // Spawn around the parent object and in the space coordinates of the parent (including its rotation and scale)
            //go.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-25f, 25f), Random.Range(-25f, 25f), Random.Range(-25f, 25f));

            // Spawn them around another object
            if (turrent != null)
            {
                go.transform.position = turrent.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(-100f, 100f), Random.Range(-100f, 100f), Random.Range(-100f, 100f));
                GameObject objectToMove = Instantiate(objectToMovePrefab);
                objectToMove.tag = "Object To Move";
                objectToMove.transform.position = go.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }

    private void GeneratePointsInTracks()
    {
        var startPoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Start Point");
        var curvedLines = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Curved Line");

        for (int i = 0; i < startPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfPointsInTrack; x++)
            {
                GameObject go = Instantiate(tracksPrefab, curvedLines[i].transform);
                go.name = "Point In Track";
                go.transform.position = turrent.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(-100f, 100f), Random.Range(-100f, 100f), Random.Range(-100f, 100f));

                if(x == numberOfPointsInTrack - 1)
                {
                    go.name = "Last Point In Track";

                    Vector2 p = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * drawRadius.xradius;
                    go.transform.position = drawRadius.transform.position + new Vector3(p.x, 0, p.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // The problem is that it's taking time until it's creating the positions for each curved line
    // Either to wait with startcourtine or to check why it's taking time
    private void GetTracksPositions()
    {
        var curvedLines = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Curved Line");
        for(int i = 0; i < curvedLines.Length; i++)
        {
            var positions = new Vector3[curvedLines[i].GetComponent<LineRenderer>().positionCount];
            curvedLines[i].GetComponent<LineRenderer>().GetPositions(positions);
            tracksPointsPositions.Add(positions);
        }
    }

    void Move(Vector3[] positions, GameObject[] objectsToMove)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Length; i++)
        {
            objectsToMove[i].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objectsToMove[i].transform.position,
                                                    positions[index],
                                                    speed * Time.deltaTime);

            if (objectsToMove[i].transform.position == positions[index])
            {
                index += 1;
            }

            if (index == positions.Length)
                index = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

There are 5 objects to move. and there are 5 tracks on each track there are a lot of positions.
Each one of the 5 objects to move start at the start position the first point in a track and then should move along the track path.

This List contains the arrays of positions for each track :

```
private List<Vector3[]> tracksPointsPositions = new List<Vector3[]>();
```

so each object to move should move on array of positions.

Each Curved Line for example Curved Line0 contains 5 points each point connect a line and create some line with some curves and this is a path that object to move should move on.

Each path contains array of many positions.

[image: Tracks]

When I'm running the game first time at start the objects to move are in the start positions of each track one object to move on the start of a track.

but then after 5 seconds they are not in the start position and not moving at all.

I tried now this in the Update I changed it to :

```
if (test == true)
        {
            if (tracksPointsPositions.Count > 0)
            {
                Move(tracksPointsPositions, objectsToMove);
            }
        }
```

In the Move :

```
void Move(List<Vector3[]> positions, GameObject[] objectsToMove)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Length; i++)
        {
            objectsToMove[i].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objectsToMove[i].transform.position,
                                                    positions[index][index],
                                                    speed * Time.deltaTime);

            if (objectsToMove[i].transform.position == positions[index][index])
            {
                index += 1;
            }

            if (index == positions.Count)
                index = 0;
        }
    }
```

Now the objects to move are moving but off the track/s and after short time they are moving back to the start position.  They never move on the track/s from the start to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you iterator all tracking position in same frame.
the result of your code should be like object appear on the last position

```
if(tracksPointsPositions.Count > 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tracksPointsPositions.Count; i++) {
        Move(tracksPointsPositions[i], objectsToMove);
    }
}
```

For my example

```
    private int trackIndex = 0; //current destination position on track points
    public Vector2[] TracksPointsPositions;

    void Update() {
        Move();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moving between 2 point
    /// </summary>
    private void Move() {

        var ms = 10 * Time.deltaTime;
        var distance = Vector2.Distance(this.transform.position, TracksPointsPositions[trackIndex]);

        if(distance <= 0) {
            trackIndex = (trackIndex + 1) % TracksPointsPositions.Length; //move to next track point when reach current destination
        }

        var origin = this.transform.position;
        var destination = TracksPointsPositions[trackIndex];
        this.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(origin, destination, ms );

    }
```

Comment: but the objects to move are all in this script I mean I don't want to add this script to each object to move so how can I make that all the objectsToMove to move in the Move method ?

Comment: I my opinion you should to create EnemyTrackBehaviour to control behaviour of the enemy which it need the tracking position instead to built up in GenerateEnemyTrackSystem. The GenerateEnemyTrackSystem should 'Generate' tracking route and put it in to EnemyTrackBehaviour instead of control them.